move_base with optitrack
I am trying to integrate optitrack (vicon) tracking system with move_base. I was able to compute the world (from optitrack) to odom frame using this transformation: (odom_to_base_link * base_link_to_world).inverse(). I attached my tf frames output (tb3 is my robot's position frame from optitrack, I used it to compute base_link_to_world).

I was able to verify that my tf frames are setup correctly by ensuring that the tb3 frame coincides with the base_frame in rviz.

Then I setup my move_base planner with the following settings:
costmap_global:
    global_frame: world
    rolling_window: true
    track_unknown_space: true
costmap_local:
    global_frame: world
    rolling_window: true

But this didn't work. When I tried to set a goal position, the robot was not able to get there. The local path and global path seemed sensible in rviz but the robot did not follow either path. Also, the issue only appears on the real-hardware. The method seems to work fine with Gazebo sim (maybe because odom does not dirft there). I tried using different robots, but I had the same issue. I would really appreceate any help with this 
